# Não consigo ligar o pod_mysql em Netware

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

Tenho um servidor NetWare IA32 NLM 6 50, com Apache 2, PHP 5.0.5 e MYSQL 4.

No `php.ini` já liguei os drivers PDO, que já vem embutidos no PHP 5 e mesmo assim não consigo comunicar com o MySQL:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Erro ao executar o php:

> Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in SYS:/apache2/htdocs/Newsletters/databases.php on line 26

O que fazer para resolver?

Comment: Netware existe ainda? :) Procure descrever bem sucintamente seu problema no título. Para indicar as tecnologias você usa as *tags* que não podem ser reproduzidas no título.

Comment: Obrigado. Pelos vistos netware ainda existe. :) Não existe tag para Netware.

Comment: Você instalou o PDO como um pacote pecl? [No manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) tem mais detalhes, "PDO ships with PHP 5.1, and is available as a PECL extension for PHP 5.0; PDO requires the new OO features in the core of PHP 5, and so will not run with earlier versions of PHP."